# Textbox Event Handling in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a situation, where I am validating a textbox for enabling the button. If the textbox is empty the button should be disabled and vice verse. I can handle the code and achieve the solution, if I write the logic in the code behind of the XAML but I feel thats not the correct way and the event should be handled from the viewModel instead of the code behind.

Here is what I have done:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,192,264,0" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         x:Name="txtDNCNotes" Text="{Binding Path=DNCNotes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         Visibility="{Binding Path=DNCNoteTxtVisibility}" Grid.Column="1"
         behaviour:TextBoxFilters.IsBoundOnChange="True"
         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public string DNCNotes
{
    get { return _dncNotes; }
    set { 
        if (_dncNotes == value) return; 
        _dncNotes = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("DNCNotes"); 
    }
}
```

**Code behind**

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = LayoutRoot.DataContext as NextLeadWizardViewModel;
    BindingExpression binding = txtDNCNotes.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    ctx.ShowDoNotContact();
}
```

I am trying to write following code in the viewModel to achieve the solution but not sure what to write.

```
public void ShowDoNotContact()
{
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("DNCNotes");

    //myBinding.Source =  DataContext as NextLeadWizardViewModel;

    myBinding.Source = txtDNCNotes;

    myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DNCNotes");
    myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtDNCNotes, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);

    if (_dncNotes == null)
        OkCommand.IsEnabled = false;
    else
        OkCommand.IsEnabled = CanEnableOk();

}
```

Comment: Dont know if i get you right..."I have a situation, where I am validating a textbox for enabling the button. " Use the CanExecute of a Command?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion, all I meant that I wanted to write the validation in ViewModel instead of code behind. I never thought of CanExecute, but I am going to explore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to validate a `TextBox` which would disable the button, i would use a `command`, something similar to this;

```
    private ICommand showDCNoteCommand;
    public ICommand ShowDCNoteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.showDCNoteCommand == null)
            {
                this.showDCNoteCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DCNoteFormExecute, this.DCNoteFormCanExecute);
            }

            return this.showDCNoteCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool DCNoteFormCanExecute()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DCNotes);

    }

    private void DCNoteFormExecute()
    {
        DCNoteMethod(); //This a method that changed the text
    }
```

This would ensure that the user is unable to continue, or save to progress as the TextBox should not accept a null or empty value, shown within the `DCNoteFormCanExecute()` (the DCNotes is property that you have defined within your Viewmodel).

and in the xaml, bind it to the button like so;

```
<Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="20" x:Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Command="{Binding ShowDCNoteCommand}"
```

For validation, you could do something simple like so, using attribute validation, using this reference `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`;

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "DCNotes is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,5}$", ErrorMessage = "DCNotes must contain no more then 5 characters")] //You can change the length of the property to meet the DCNotes needs
    public string DCNotes
    {
        get { return _DCNotes; }
        set
        {
            if (_DCNotes == value)
                return;

            _DCNotes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DCNotes");
        }
    }
```

and within the xaml, you could create a `Resource` to highlight the box to notify the user of the textbox not been filled out;

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="4" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="4" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>

            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I hope this helps, otherwise, here's the link that might help;
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat

OR

http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-textbox-validation-idataerrorinfo.html#.UOv01G_Za0t

Comment: Can you suggest the <Style> xaml code, to silverlight equivalent like `<Style TargetType="TextBlock">`

I am unable to find for `<style.triggers>`

Comment: I've not touched Silverlight before, but you could use a Resource page rather then specifying that code directly in your page. have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645061%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: `this.showDNCNoteCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DNCNoteFormExecute, this.DNCNoteFormCanExecute);
                }`

This gives me error as relaycommand expects only one parameter

Comment: You need to have a RelayCommandBaseClass and within there have the method that takes in the paramters to enable you to achieve this. Follow the links provided to give you a better understanding of how to do this :).

Comment: Why u have mentioned the same style tag for twice?

Comment: The first tag is used for margin of the text box, keeping the text-box in one place, like what you use for HTML/CSS. the second style tag is referring to the Text box that you want to validate.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewModel is an acceptable place to add supporting properties for your View that do not effect your model. For example, something along the lines of:

```
    public bool DncCanExecute
    {
        get
        {
           return "" != _dncNotes;
        }
    }

    public string DNCNotes
    {
        get { return _dncNotes; }
        set { 
            if (_dncNotes == value) return;
            if (("" == _dncNotes && "" != value) || ("" != _dncNotes && "" == value))
            {
                _dncNotes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DncCanExecute");
            }
            else
            {
                _dncNotes = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("DNCNotes");
        }
    }
```

From there, you can just bind the `Button.IsEnabled` property to the `DncCanExecute` property to get the desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I simply bind the DncCanExecute like
       `Button.IsEnabled = DncCanExecute;`

Comment: I guess you should read something about Commands. [Understanding Routed Events and Commands In WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx)

Comment: or will I need to bind something like this. `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, Source={StaticResource MyObservableCollection}}"/>` Let me know.

Comment: I am looking into thanks. BTW, `return "" != _dncNotes;` gives me compilation error `;` expected. Thanks though

Comment: @DotNetGeek `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding DncCanExecute}" />` or you could also do `Button.SetBinding(Button.IsEnabledProperty, "DncCanExecute")`. Both assume that your button's `DataContext` is the ViewModel containing the property.

Comment: @newb: Why does `public bool DncCanExecute()
    {
        get
        {
           return "" != _dncNotes;
        }
    }
`
gives me compilation error as `; expected` ?

Comment: @DotNetGeek No clue. It compiles perfectly fine for me using VS2010 and VS2012. You can do `return _dncNotes != "";`, I just prefer the other way to prevent accidents like `_dncNotes = "";`.

Comment: You mentioneed ` DncCanExecute()` as function, I removed the braces, and error was gone.

Comment: @DotNetGeek Ah. You caught me there. How embarrassing. I'll edit the answer to reflect that. Thanks.